# Webcam live stream in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, stream

I have a webcam placed on the top of a building and I have to show the live video on a wordpress page. What are the best ways to do it? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The user interface of webcams is usually or even should be password protected in order to avoid abuse so there arises a problem if you want to make the stream publicly available. Maybe you can try motioneyeos to achieve your goal.

Comment: I saw on the net a solution that uploads via FTP webcam snapshots in a wordpress folder and with react webcam plugin show them on page. Is it a valid solution?

Comment: I can't find that solution so I don't know.